# Issue with scaling of views of a pageViewController embedded in a container view

Tags: swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am currently working on a small Ipad App and I am having some issues with the frame sizes of two `UIViewController`. These two get called through a `UIPageViewController`, to allow scrolling from one view to the other. The Page View Controller in turn is embedded in a container view, as shown below:

[image: Image1]]

As I want to display some graphs in one of the viewcontrollers, I have additional views within it, which are then filled with plots. The issue is that for some reason when this viewController is called for the first time, the frame size of the entire view is off.

[image: Image2]]

This leads to the plots being wrongly scaled. When I rotate the device, the problem disappears, as the plots are redrawn with the correct frame size in 'didRotate() {...}'

[image: Image3]]
[image: Image4]]

So when I rotate the device twice, I get the plots I wanted.

I've been racking my brains on how to fix this issue, but so far nothing has worked. The only thing that has given me somewhat of a clue what is going on is, that the frame size of the container view and the views of the pageView don't match, before reloading everything.

I am new to stack overflow and I don't know if this is enough to go on. If you need any additional information, let me know and I would be happy to provide more context.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

Try using this in your code:

```
    pageViewer.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    contentView.addSubview(pageViewer.view) // the UIView in the UIPageViewController

    let views: [String: Any] = ["ChartView": pageViewer.view as Any]

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[ChartView]-0-|",
        options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
        metrics: nil,
        views: views))
    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[ChartView]-0-|",
        options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
        metrics: nil,
        views: views))
```

Alternatively you can try messing with this feature:

[image: Autoresizing in size inspector]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick answer! This might sound stupid, but where should I add it?

Comment: No problem not stupid at all! You want to put the PageView inside a UIView (contentView) in the main view controller, and then put the code there (in the main view controller), whenever you want to call on your pageview

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIMRn_LdvOg Also this is a great tutorial! (it has a little bug in it but just create a property named index on your DataViewController)

Comment: Ok, I tried to add your snippet of code to my main view controller. But it didn't make much of a difference. The issue seems to be, that the views i call through my pageviewcontroller, do not match the size of the containerview the pageviewcontroller is embedded in, in the initial load. One solution would be to constrain the frame size of the views containing the plots... but that's a bad solution as the plots won't scale when the device is rotated. Any other suggestions? Thanks for the help sofar!

Comment: Hi, well I'm not sure exactly how you did it in your project, I really do think you should take a look at the youtube tutorial, it's about 20 minutes long and the way he does it is actually less about the storyboard and segues, and more about instantiating the views and the page viewer via code. This makes things a bit more annoying because it's less fun to write code than it is to use the storyboard lol, however you do have a lot more control over the constraints, and it gives you the workaround for having different sized containers. I really hope that will work for you.. let me know!

Comment: I actually encountered something similar in my own project over the weekend - try maybe messing with the Autoresizing feature in the Size Inspector on the storyboard (for the main contentview). I'll add a little screenshot in the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the solution was to change the call of the pageviews "subViews". Instead of calling my view controllers by `if let firstViewController  = ...` in `viewDidLoad`, I just call them in `viewDidAppear`. No reason why, but it solved the issue.